# AJAX Post HTML Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe

I'm having an issue with sending some HTML code using AJAX please see my code below

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" width="10" height="10" id="awc_frame"></iframe>
<script>var iframe = document.getElementById("awc_frame");</script>
```

Here is the AJAX code below

```
<script> 

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mobileView.php",
        data: { val : iframe },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data); 
        }
    })
</script>
```

The code isn't sending the variable to the PHP file. Looking into the Network side of things it sends text ie if I put "" around iframe it sends this code 
"val = iframe" but not the actual code within the iframe. The "var iframe"does work and pulls back the HTML code of the iframe

Please tell me what I'm doing wrongly.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I'm sorry. It's not the HTML code within the iFrame I need to send, It's the entire iFrame code I need to send.

**Another Edit: What I'm trying to accomplish when a visitor from my company goes to my website I would like Javascript or Jquery to load an internal website from the visitors computer and then have all of the code from that website that's on the client's end to be sent to a Server which will store the entire iFrame code in a database.**

Comment: What is exactly that you want to send here? IFrame's loaded HTML?

Comment: Yes. The entire loaded HTML from the iFrame needs to be sent to a PHP document where it will be uploaded to a database

Answer (score 0):

what are you trying to do?

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("awc_frame");
```

above code is an javascript object of your iframe which contains a lot of properties.. since you are using jQuery, you could get that with:

```
var iframe = $('#awc_frame');
```

keep in mind that above code is the element it self in jquery object format you could get element object like this:

```
var iframe = $('#awc_frame')[0];
```

** you're doing something wrong.

if you're trying to get iframe HTML content:

```
var iframe_contents = $("#awc_frame").contents();
```

if you explain more about what you are trying to do, i can update my answer to suit you.

*** UPDATE ***
considering what you are trying to do..

**Method #1: (Easy Way)**

you could use php to fetch content of the website you need:

```
<?php
    $contents = file_get_contents('http://www.w3schools.com');
    // Saving $contents to database...
?>
```

**Method #2: (Hard Way)**

as @mdziekon said, you first should wait until your iframe gets loaded then:

```
var iframe = $("#awc_frame");

iframe.on("load", function () {
    var contents = $(this)[0].innerHTML;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mobileView.php",
        data: {
            val: contents
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

hope it solves your problem

Comment: Yes I need all of those properties in the code, So the entire code from an iFrame with all the fully loaded website sent to the PHP document.

Comment: it think it's better for you to change your scenario, instead of loading website content on your browser and sending it's content to server, you could do the same with your PHP script.

Comment: @HaroonBaig why do you need properties of iframe in your php script?

Comment: I need a client-side user to load an iFrame on their side and then that needs to be sent to a server.

Comment: i understand that, what are you trying to achieve? sending iframe DOM to server is impossible because it's useless..

Comment: Okay. I am trying to send an Internal page from the Client-Side user. Which has it's crossdomain policy set for any website to access. And that iframe. Unfortunately I am not aloud to disclose the contents of the webpage but it's not useless.

Comment: the website you are trying to load should set crossdomain policy not yours.

Comment: I know that. I have changed the website now to a test file on my web server. So I have a file on my server called index.php and test.php I am getting index to load the code from test.php and try send that to a server,

Comment: also, i didn't understand what you mean when you said 'Internal Page'. what are you going to do when iframe loads? transfer it to php to do save it's content to database? if it's yes you don't need javascript to do that, just load iframe for user to see, and just pass address of the iframe to php to load contents there.

Comment: Hi, I think that's what I need. But I don't want PHP to load the page I want the client-sided loaded iFrame data so all the code on the page as you'd see by Viewing the page source on a browser is saved on to the database. I know how to save html code on to a database but not how to get the code from the file. Also by internal page I mean on an intranet like localhost for example.

Comment: It didn't work :(. I don't understand my crossdomain policy is set to everyone so it should load. http://haroonb.com/crossdomain.xml

Comment: open inspection in chrome, send an screenshot of your ajax headers and response.

Comment: prntscr.com/cdz7n8 prntscr.com/cdz7tx prntscr.com/cdz7ze

Comment: the code you ran is your  own, it isn't the one i suggested, and also please send screenshots of your ajax request in Chrome -> Inspection -> Network section

Comment: Hi, This is the AJAX request. It's not showing any code. http://prntscr.com/cdzjo2 please note in the form code it's not sending any data apart from val: (nothing). Also I am using your code now http://prntscr.com/cdzjy2 @Pezhvak

Comment: hi, i'm working on it right now, i realized you just uploaded crossdomain.xml on your website which is used for Adobe Flash (deprecated), if you want other websites to be able to send ajax requests to your website you should add  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); to your main php script. infrom me when you're done.

Comment: Okay done. Please could you explain this. If a client accesses a webpage with an iframe that goes onto a different website. Does Jquery/Javascript block the code (DOM) from being sent to a server?

Comment: you didn't set it right, idk if you have a php framework or you're just writing php clean code, but if you set it right you can see it in Network section of chrome (or any other debugging tool) http://prnt.sc/ce18n0, yes, that's right. not only chrome.. many other browsers do it as well.

Answer (score 0):

This would send the entire html inside the iframe.

```
var iframe = $('#awc_frame').html();
```

Comment: Yes. I need to send the entire html code within the iframe

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `var iframe` does not contain HTML of the iframe element - it contains a DOM Node, which is kind of a wrapper around the iframe element (it contains various properties of that element, including the HTML).
Next thing, you probably want to wait for the iframe to completely load all the contents, so you'll have to bind to the `load` event of it.

Something like this should work:

```
var $iframe = $("#awc_frame");

$iframe.on("load", function () {
    var iframeHTML = $iframe[0].contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
    // jQuery alternative
    var iframeHTML = $iframe.contents().find("body").html();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mobileView.php",
        data: {
            val: iframeHTML
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

#### Super important thing in this example

Just one more thing - please note that for websites outside of your own domain, this code won't work (due to Same Origin Policy). Any other code won't work too.

Comment: That's because you are trying to fetch domain outside of your own domain. As I already told - it's impossible to do.

Comment: I don't understand but if I go into Console and try calling iframe it works. But why doesn't it send the code?

Comment: Read about Same Origin Policy. Things you have already loaded into your browser are **not** exactly the same things that JavaScript lets you reference.

Comment: I tried the same thing on my server and had the same error. I even placed a crossdomain file allowing access from all. And the error occurred.

Comment: It's getting all the code and place it in a var which is okay but then it will not send via AJAX to a PHP script.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the AJAX in this code, so you either try to reach wrong PHP script URL, or you are not sending properly formatted data (contentType). Check your Network console for request errors.

Comment: Hi, My website is haroonb.com, I have loaded the Console and it will not send anything the variable is called iFrame. Please could you help me check to see what I'm doing wrong. I really appreciate your help

Comment: First of all, there is an error on your side, which might prevent rest of the code from executing. Besides, if you want me to debug your code, please provide a limited test case (a separate page where you only load the iframe and the script).

Comment: Well, the request returns 404, to you are just making a request to the wrong URL. As for the content retrieval, you got your ``var contents = ...`` line wrong (it should be eg. ``var contents = iframe.contents().find("body").html()``.

Comment: Hi there is no var contents in the script. Also I haven't created the .php file I need to create it after I've done this. I'm currently using Google Chrome Network tools to see what code is being sent to the server. Please could you check again at the updated code

Comment: The fix I've provided in the previous comment did the trick. I don't know why you've changed the code to even more buggy version...

Comment: Sorry @mdziekon Oh your code works :) Thank you very much :)

Comment: How do I show the entire code not just the text but the entire webpage code?

Answer (score 0):

Since javascript has problems with getting the HTML from a cross-domain iframe, you can't do this across domains. However, why not just send the iframe's src attribute to the PHP page, and then just use file_get_contents to get the HTML, and then store that? Problem solved:

Javascript:

```
var iframe = $('#awc_frame').prop('src');

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "posttest.php",
    data: { val : iframe },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data); 
    }
});
```

PHP:

```
$html = file_get_contents($_POST['val']);
```

Comment: Because the page that needs to be loaded is on an intranet and the web server is not on that intranet domain so it can't load or access the website on the server end. Only the client can see the page as their on the domain/intranet.